# BitLocker metadata for the encrypted drive is not valid (0x80310010)

Tags: bitlocker

I'm moving an external drive to a new computer.

The drive is protected with Bitlocker, but I can unlock it and view the contents.

However, when I try to configure auto-unlock I see:

```
C:\>manage-bde -autounlock -enable d:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.17763
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80310010):
The BitLocker metadata for the encrypted drive is not valid. You can attempt to repair the drive to restore access.
```

Is there a way to rebuild the metadata?

Clearly the metadata is valid enough to unlock the volume, so I'm wondering if the error message is even correct.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation revealed that the error message was incorrect.

The cause of the problem was that the disk was marked as readonly.

After using `diskpart` to clear the readonly flag, then locking and unlocking the volume, `manage-bde -autounlock -enable d:` worked correctly.

```dos
C:\>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.17763.1554

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: HYPER-V

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    499 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3     D   DATA         ReFS   Partition   7449 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> select volume 3

Volume 3 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : Yes
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> exit

C:\>manage-bde -lock d:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.17763
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume D: is now locked

C:\>manage-bde -unlock d: -pw
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.17763
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Enter the password to unlock this volume:
The password successfully unlocked volume D:.

C:\>manage-bde -autounlock -enable d:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.17763
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Key Protectors Added:
    External Key:
      ID: {3CEFC24B-BBBF-4818-A128-9FA0E87E872D}
      External Key File Name:
        3CEFC24B-BBBF-4818-A128-9FA0E87E872D.BEK
      Automatic unlock enabled.
```